# Need help in choosing Collection type

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, hashmap

I need to return a file ID (`Integer`) and success or fail (`boolean`) values from a method. I have 3 options in my mind.

One is to convert the both the values String and make the return type as `ArrayList`.

The second option is to use the `HashMap`. Since those both values doesn't have any dependency I am not sure whether I can use this type or not.

Third one is to convert both into String objects and return a comma separated string.

Please suggest me which one is the better solution for me.

Comment: Never use Strings in this way lest you want your code to give off a bad smell. I wonder if the method is being asked to do too much, if you need to break it down into several methods, either that or have it change the state of the object that contains it. Note that having said that, I would treat a file ID as a String since it really isn't a numeric type at all -- you'd never add or subtract with it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is correct. In addition, there is no such type as `ArrayList<String, String>`.

Comment: @WChargin The OP didn't posted such type.

Comment: Create a new class with three fields and return the reference. You may use this comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other possible solutions:

- have the method return the file ID String or int. If it fails, have it throw an Exception.
- Split it into two methods, one called fileIdExists() that returns a boolean and the other `getFileId()` that returns the ID. The latter should still throw an exception if there is no ID just as a fail-safe.
- Or use a wrapper object to hold all necessary fields (as per artbristol's great suggestion).

Comment: `fileid` is an integer. Please don't convert it to a String to just cast it back to an int again.

Comment: @poitroae: what the h3ll are you talking about? Where do you see me suggesting this?

Comment: ""have the method return the file ID String.""

Comment: @poitroae: exactly, and it should not be converted back into an integer. It should remain a String since it isn't a numeric entity.

Comment: The OP says it is an integer.

Comment: @poitroae: and I have suggested to the OP in comments to the original post that he change this. Explain to me when you would do mathematics with a file id? When would you add it, subtract it, divide by it, etc? Why should it be an int?

Comment: Why would one do this?

Comment: @poitroae: also because as a String it would be immutable.

Comment: Sorry, but your arguments are nonsense.

Comment: @poitroae: OK changed to return String or int. Will let OP decide. But please also see [this link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=192) to see why this bothers me so.

Answer (score 1):

**Let the integer's value include the success-state**.
This only works if your integer can only be positive (which usually is the case for `fileid`'s).

1. **Return -1 on failure**
2. **Return the file-id on success**

Comment: Why should this be a comment?  It's a solution to this issue that many people use.  Not my favorite solution, but have an upvote anyway to counter.

Comment: ugh, this isn't C. Use a wrapper object.

Comment: @artbristol Still the most efficient way. Not all of C++ is bad. :)